# Why isn't this statement marked as completely covered by eclemma?

Tags: java, code-coverage, emma

I am using EclEmma in Eclipse (more specifically, RSA 8).  I have the following statement in my code:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Collection collection) {
    return (collection == null) || collection.isEmpty();
}
```

and I have the following tests:

```
@Test public void isEmpty_nullCase() {
    assertTrue(CollectionUtil.isEmpty(null));
}
@Test public void isEmpty_listCase() {
    assertTrue(CollectionUtil.isEmpty(new ArrayList()));
}
```

but for some reason, the statement is showing up as yellow.  What part of it am I not testing?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Just for the sake of precision, I would recommend calling your method isNullOrEmpty(), so that callers know what to expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about an ArrayList that has a value, and is therefore not empty?

Comment: Oh yeah.  Duh!  That was it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following test case:

```
@Test
public void checkNonNullNonEmpty(){
   Assert.assertFalse(CollectionUtil.isEmpty(new ArrayList<String>(){
    {
      add("blah blah blah....!");
    }
  });
}
```

You have only tested true conditions. Ideally there are 4 possible combinations of `return (collection == null) || collection.isEmpty();`
 statement. 1st condition can be T/F and 2nd can be T/F. So totall 4 possibilities. You have covered 3 only. The above test case will cover **non null non empty** possibility.